# How To Make Dynamic Link On Email in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, mail-sender

I want to ask something.
I build a simple email sender using asp.net core 2.0 and I want to send an email with a link to redirect the receiver into my web page like email authentication but I don't know how to make the callback URL.

I use :

`<a href='https://"+Request.Scheme+"/Users/Userrole'>Click Here</a>`

but the link in email was http:/Users/Userrole

Please tell me how to get the dynamic URL to my page, because using Localhost:443xx/User/Userrole is not elegant and does not work when I run on my local computer

Edit,
the very simple method to do this action is 
`<a href='https://"+this.Request.Host+"/Users/Userrole'>Click Here</a>`

Thanks to FrustatedDeveloper for this answer

Comment: `Request.Scheme`  will return scheme of url ex:`http` you can use: `srting  Request.Url.Authority`

Comment: Do i need add other library?,  because when i type request.url the message show url not define in current context.

Comment: opps.. I'm sorry. you work with asp.net core I missed it

Comment: you can use  `this.Request.PathBase   or this.Request.Host`

Comment: Ok sir,  i will try it.  Thank you very much for your response

Comment: Thankyou very much, the second method using ```this.request.host``` is work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Asp.Net Core

In Asp.Net Core you can use the following to get the URL:

```
var url = $"{Context.Request.Scheme}://{Context.Request.Host}{Context.Request.Path}";
var link = $"<a href='{url}'>Click here</a>";
```

If you need to get the query string then you can use:

```
var queryString = Context.Host.QueryString;
```

Please check the following resource: [HttpRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

If you include `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` then you can also use:

```
var url = httpContext.Request.GetEncodedUrl();
```

Or

```
var url = httpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
```

---

### Original Answer (Asp.Net/MVC framework)

To create a dynamic URL you can use the [UrlHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) `@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")` along with `Request.Url.Authority` for the domain and `Request.Url.Scheme` for the scheme (using http or https).

```
var url = $"{Request.Url.Scheme}://{Request.Url.Authority}{@Url.Action("UserRole","Users")}";
var link = $"<a href='{url}'>Click here</a>";
```

Assuming your site has a domain `www.example.com` this would procude a URL like:

```
https://www.example.com/users/userrole
```

The above uses [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) to combine the string variables.

Comment: i'm sorry i was type like your code, but i have error 'HTTPRequest' doesn't contain a definition for 'Url', do i need import some library?

Comment: @DewaDwi Hi, sorry, I didn't notice the .Net core tag.  I've updated my answer :)

Comment: im trying to do the same thing in my asp.net core 3.0 app but its not working. im trying to generate a link to send thru email in my controller.

Comment: @helloworld have you tried using the [Url.Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.urlhelper.link?view=aspnetcore-2.1) method?